# on iOS my absolute element only shows up to the height of the page when it is translated into view

Tags: ios, reactjs, create-react-app

I am using React and create-react-app to create and app and in said app I am using a sidebar that I have translated off the page when the screen-size is at 768px which will be translated onto the page with a click of the hamburger

```
    .sidebar {
       transform: translateX(-180px);
       position: absolute;
       overflow-y: visible;
       background-color: #202020;
       transition: .5s;
       z-index: 10;
    }

    .sidebar.is-active {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
```

this works perfectly on firefox and chrome browsers but when I use ipads and iphones to check, when I click the hamburger, it only shows the sidebar up to the height of where the page was and will not scroll down any more,

however, when I go off the safari app and back in, the sidebar is fully visible and I can scroll past the height of the component.

Why is this occurring and how do I make it so that I don't have to exit and reload the safari app?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put my body (parent) as position: relative and this seemed to solve the issue